# Perl script failing to open file for writing on first run but succeeding on second run

Tags: perl, ubuntu

This script fails on the first run but succeeds the second time it is run with the same output_dir argument.

`$output_dir` is an argument passed in by user such as "/home/user/mydir".

Failing line:

```
open(StepOne, ">$output_dir/Step_One_Create_Resources.sh");
```

OS is Ubuntu 12.04

This seems like a permissions issue but I'm running the script as root.

Comment: Where's the ` or die $!` behind the `open` call? This will give you more information about the problem. Or if you're lazy, just `use autodie;` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, maybe it is true that the $output_dir didn't exist when you call open(StepOne, ">$output_dir/Step_One_Create_Resources.sh") for the first time.So ,I strongly advise you to wait until the directory is created.

```
do{
}while(!(-e $output_dir));
open(StepOne, ">$output_dir/Step_One_Create_Resources.sh") or die $!;
```

this will make sure you open the output_dir just after the output_dir is actually created!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing this issue. When a directory that doesn't exist was being passed in as the output directory, the script would create the dir but it was failing to open a file at that location. The script runs fine when the output dir already exists.

Comment: Change your line to `open(StepOne, ">$output_dir/Step_One_Create_Resources.sh") or die $!;` and you'd be able to figure such issues faster.